# × Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client

Please help me resolve this error:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
This is my code:

```js
index.js: 

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css'
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import ApolloProvider from './ApolloProvider'

ReactDOM.render(

  <
  ApolloProvider / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

ApolloProvider.js:

```js
import React from 'react'
import App from './App'
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client'
import {
  InMemoryCache
} from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import {
  createHttpLink
} from 'apollo-link-http'
import {
  ApolloProvider
} from '@apollo/react-hooks'

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http//localhost:5000'
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})

export default ( <
  ApolloProvider client = {
    client
  } >
  <
  App / >
  <
  /ApolloProvider>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
ReactDOM.render(
  ApolloProvider ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

or update the provider to export a component

```
export default function provider() {
return (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>
);
}
```